# Start an activity from a listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I have a listview and, I am trying to start an activity from the listview by `startActivity(class.java);`

```
public class ll2 extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] myList = new String[] {"Accrington Stanley", "Aldershot Town", "Barnet", "Bradford City", "Burton Albion", "Bury", "Cheltenham Town", "Chesterfield", "Crewe A", "Gillingham", "Hereford Utd", "Lincoln City", "Macclesfield T", "Morecombe", "Northampton T", "Oxford Utd", "Port Vale", "Rotherham Utd", "Shrewsbury T", "Southend Utd", "Stevenage", "Stockport C", "Torquay Utd", "Wycombe W"};              
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList));
        setContentView(lv); }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

        if ("Bradford City".equals(MyList()[position])){
            startActivity(Bradford.java);}
        }
}
```

I am getting a error with this line `if("Bradford City".equals(MyList()[position]))`  method `myList()` is undefined for the type ll2

I have tried all sorts of methods, and I cannot get anything to work.  All I want to do is for each team in the list have a separate java file(Class) With activities in them.

Comment: What it MyList()??? Have you copied and pasted it from somewhere? It seems to be a method returning your list view but you did not put the definition.

Comment: myList relates toi the String[] myList[] {"accrington line this listactivity is copied from here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html but I have changed and tried to add a activity

Comment: MyList? Check the case, u have declared it as myList...

Comment: I think you would do well to use an IDE (I recommend Eclipse) and pay attention to the compile errors.  Code completion in the IDE will help you out a lot also.

Comment: I know I corrected that, still same error

Comment: This clearly shows that you haven't even followed the most basic android tutorials. `startActivity(Bradford.java)` isn't even CLOSE to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyList()[position]` should be `myList[position]`.
Next you can not start an activity like this `startActivity(Bradford.java);`. For starting a new activity you need to create and intent and then set the Activity class. Then you can call startActivity with that intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Bradford.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you need to add `Bradford` activity to your manifest as well.

Comment: I have added Bradford activity as  <activity android:name="Bradford" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity> but I get an error on next. cannot be resolved

Comment: next should be intent, my bad.modified the answer with the same.

Comment: ok I've managed to get no errors run and it runs but when I click on Bradford nothing happens         
       Intent myList = new Intent();
            myList.setClass(this, Bradford.class);
            
            if ("Bradford City".equals(myList))
            startActivity(Bradford.java);

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this all day and thought id post it everywhere i could.

I got the a little easier answer. Basically i turned it into a string so i could just type out what i wanted where.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (item.equals("Economy"))
        {

    Intent intent = new Intent(packages.this, economy.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
    else if (item.equals("Basic"))
    {

Intent intent = new Intent(packages.this, basic.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
    else if (item.equals("Professional"))
    {

Intent intent = new Intent(packages.this, professional.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```