# Start an activity from a listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start an activity from a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786715/start-an-activity-from-a-listview)

I have 24 teams in a list, I have 24 separate .java classes for each team with information about those teams.  When the user click on an item(Team) in the list I want to goto that teams java file(Class) and display there information. below is the code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ll2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] myList = new String[] {"Accrington Stanley", "Aldershot Town", "Barnet", "Bradford City", "Burton Albion", "Bury", "Cheltenham Town", "Chesterfield", "Crewe A", "Gillingham", "Hereford Utd", "Lincoln City", "Macclesfield T", "Morecombe", "Northampton T", "Oxford Utd", "Port Vale", "Rotherham Utd", "Shrewsbury T", "Southend Utd", "Stevenage", "Stockport C", "Torquay Utd", "Wycombe W"};              
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList));
        setContentView(lv);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,int position, long id) {
       Intent myList = new Intent();
        myList.setClass(this, Bradford.class);

        if ("Bradford City".equals(myList))
            startActivity(Bradford.java);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have setup the Bradford class and I have registered this in android manifest but when I click on bradford nothing happens, also when I try to set up another intent for another team the mylist value cannot be used again.

How do I make this work

Comment: myList is not a list at all, but an Intent. Of course an intent is not going to be equal to "Bradford City" which is a String.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare an intent with a String, but you need to compare the String that comes from the Listview.
Try it this way:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,int position, long id) {
     if(((TextView)view).getText().equals("Bradford City"))
     {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bradford.class));
     }
}
```

Although this might work, doing it to 24 classes it's very inefficient.
Maybe you could try make a Switch/Case using the "position" parameter, or even add an attribute to each of your team classes that would then allow you to make an array of Teams and call the correct class on the Intent (I'm sorry if this sound confusing, it's a little bit hard to explain).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Tom, I did eventually realise that it would be easier to use position and this is what I would have used in basic, I am beginning to realise I'm trying to run before I can jump.  Currently I have something like this if (position == 10) then my first intent below would I follow this up with case for all the other classes